# How to develop a cross-platform QR Code reader?

Tags: cordova, mobile, cross-platform, qr-code, zxing

I need to build a mobile application which is able to compare data in a remote database [e.g login system] and also get a string from a QR Code. I have zero experience developing mobile applications, but found two interesting tools. PhoneGap and Mosync.

I know there is a few PhoneGap plugins for PhoneGap [like this https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iPhone/BarcodeScanner/README.md ]. But it seems to be for iOS only. Or am I wrong?

I know that zxing has a cpp port. It's possible to use it to develop the application using Mosync?

I have much more experience with C/C++ than javascript, for me would be much easier to do the work using Mosync. However, PhoneGap seems much more complete. Any recommendation for this job?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually the [same github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins) project has BarcodeScanner plugin for iOS, Android, and BlackBerry:

- [Android
  Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/Android/BarcodeScanner)
- [iOS Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/iOS/BarcodeScanner)
- [BlackBerry Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/BlackBerry/BarcodeScanner)

I have not worked with Mosync so have no idea about it. On the other hand PhoneGap is easy to use and it has wide user base so easy to get help also. Although it may still be a learning curve for you due to your background.

**Edit**

All above links are pointing to `DEPRECATED` branch of the `phonegap-plugins` which you can visit [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED). @David has mentioned the link below for the plugins repository to download the latest plugins.

Comment: As a FYI, the github repo that used to have all of the plugins has been wiped the hell out.  It now links to http://cordova.apache.org/news/2013/10/21/cordova-registry.html which in my opinion is a stepback in accessibility.  From there is a link to a directory listing web app - http://plugins.cordova.io/#/_browse/all

Comment: @David thanks, i have updated the answer. You are right it is kind of a setback and it just downloaded the source and there is not other details, readme along with it, also it just downloaded the android version of the plugin for me. I will spend some time and check it later maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 3):

I work at MoSync, and as it happens, we've done some work recently with various kinds of barcode scanning :) Ping us at @MoSyncTeam on Twitter, drop a mail to patrick  mosync.com, or use our forum and we'll help you out, and answer any questions you might have about MoSync.